# File upload and data validation as a service

Tags: grails, saas

We are in need of handling data files provided by customers to be uploaded into our web-based service. As many providers have this same need - file upload and data file validation - I thought there might be either providers of this as a service, or at least some good plugins to minimize custom coding. I have not been able to find any as a service. Does anyone know of any? If not, anything for Grails? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what validation you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Try this service: [Filepicker.io](https://www.filepicker.io/)

Answer (score 0):

As a quick answer to a design problem.  I would take a look at [RESTFul](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/13.%20Web%20Services.html) web services for tackling something like this.  Allow your service to take in an InputStream and do the validation in the service.

If you not familiar with web services I'm sure you'll undergo some learning pains but I hope this is a good starting point for you.  Enjoy :)